# How to write appropriate endpoint in Spring Boot for GET request?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, get

I have an assignment to write simple GET request.

The format that is going to be typed in URL is like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/20-08-2020
```

Server should return TODOs for that date. I did managed to write a finder method. But not sure how to write an endpoint. This is what I have so far:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{date}", consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getTasksByDateUsingURL(@PathVariable("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy") @Valid LocalDate dueDate){
    
    List<Task> tasks = taskService.getAllTasksByDate(dueDate);
    return  new ResponseEntity<List<Task>>(tasks,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is inside `RestController` class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/api/tasks")
public class TaskController {...}
```

I cannot hit this GET endpoint...

Comment: Try value="/api/tasks". You have missed a slash.

Comment: @Suman I edited. Still no luck. I was thinking to possibly write regex for dd-mm-yyyy. But also not sure. I'm testing right now...

Comment: Please share the command and output of GET api.

Comment: Try to get ride of consumes if you are hitting from browser. Because browser by default adds "text/html". If you don't remove then try with curl by adding content-type as application/json.

Comment: @Suman What do you mean by command?

Comment: @Suman I tried to hit all endpoints from Postman. I got 400

Comment: Whay is the body of 400 reponse? Maybe problem is that `@Valid` is used?

Comment: @Miljan did some of answers help?

Comment: @VladimirShefer My apology for replying so late, I remember that I did manage to make it work thanks to your answers and correcting mistakes I had in my code. Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for your problem is to get the string as parameter and parse it manually

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{date}", consumes="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getTasksByDateUsingURL(
    @PathVariable("date") 
    String date
){
    LocalDate dueDate = parse(date);
    List<Task> tasks = taskService.getAllTasksByDate(dueDate);
    return  new ResponseEntity<List<Task>>(tasks,HttpStatus.OK);

}

private LocalDate parse(String stringDate) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad, could you maybe explain why my original idea is not working? I mean, I set atPathVariable and atDateTimeFormat. Why am I not hitting endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

As author said in comments:

> When try to call the endpoint from browser, the mapping is not executed.

Seems like that the browser is sending request with wrong `Content-Type` header. Your mapping is explicitly requires only `application/json` value.

> When try to call the endpoint from Postman, the application returns 400 status.

I could not see the body of response, but I guess the problem is `@Valid` annotation on the parameter. How should Spring validate the `LocalDate`?

So the solution is to remove `consumes="application/json"` from mapping or send corresponding `Content-Type` value
and remove `@Valid` annotation from parameter.